# How to find customer complete orders by email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Please advise on my function, it doesn't work. I'm trying on new order to check if customer (might be guest, need to check by email address) have previous complete orders. If they don't, need to add an order note. Here's the function

```
function tt_coupon_note ( $order_id ) { 

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $coupon_note_text = 'Give a coupon!';

    $query = new WC_Order_Query();
    $query->set( 'billing_email', $customer_email );
    $args = array(
        'status' => 'complete',
    );
    $orders = $query->get_orders( $args );

    if (! $orders) {
        $order->add_order_note( $coupon_note_text );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'tt_coupon_note' );
```

Reference used — https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Comment: 1- try `wc_get_order($order_id)` and check if it works.
2- instead of `billing_email` set it to `customer` and try again.

Comment: @AliQorbani didn't work at all.